# Can you execute a script/workflow in NetSuite when marking appointment as completed?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

In Netsuite, on customer records under the Communication --> Events subtab, there is a button next to each confirmed appointment to mark an appointment as completed without opening the appointment and saving it. Is there a way to execute scripts or workflows when the mark completed button is clicked from the customer record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a User Event on the Event record. The `beforeSubmit` and `afterSubmit` entry points should both be fired with a `ContextType` of `MARKCOMPLETE`. See the Help documentation for the corresponding entry point for details.